# What happens when questions are updated

Tags: support, questions, edits, bump

When you update a question does it move to the top of the list like a new question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it moves it to the top of the active question list on the front page and in the active tab.

Comment: Is this still true on Stack Overflow? I looked right now, and there was a six-hour old question (*[Could a managed thread affect globals in a C dll?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18907014)*).

Comment: The average number of questions per day on Stack Overflow is at least 3000. There are 90 questions on the front page.